# Display a julian dates in a normal date in a long text

Tags: regex, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a long text like `"acbshdh2015128dfg2015009;jsg2015070"`. It contains some Julian dates like `"2015128"`, `"2015009"` and `"2015070"`. I want to display them like normal dates in this long text `"acbshdh05082015dfg01092015;jsg03112015"`.
I want to achieve it by Oracle SQL. Is there any suggestion?

I did it like

```
REGEXP_REPLACE( ColumnName, '[[:digit:]]{10}', to_char(to_date(to_number(REGEXP_SUBSTR(ColumnName,'[[:digit:]]{10}')),J),'MM/DD‌​/YYYY HH:MI:SS') )
```

however, the result is wrong.

Comment: What have you done until now?

Comment: There is a oracle function to convert a Julian date to a normal date. All I stuck now is the way to identify any Julian date in the long text correctly. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: I did it like below REGEXP_REPLACE( ColumnName, '[[:digit:]]{10}', to_char(to_date(to_number(REGEXP_SUBSTR(ColumnName,'[[:digit:]]{10}')),J),'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS') ) however, the result is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure about the expression **Julian Date** (and what do you mean by **"normal" date**)?
Please have a look at Wikipedia: [Julian day](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day)

I don't think you can do it in pure SQL, you have to write a PL/SQL function like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ConvertJulianDate(str IN VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
    res VARCHAR2(1000) := str;  
BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1..REGEXP_COUNT(str, '\d+') LOOP
        res := REGEXP_REPLACE(res, '\d+', TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(str, '\d+', 1, i), 'J'), 'mmddyyyy'), 1, i);
    END LOOP;
    RETURN res;
END;

SELECT ConvertJulianDate('acbshdh2015128dfg2015009;jsg2015070') FROM dual;

acbshdh02130805dfg10170804;jsg12170804
```

Just for clarification: **Julian Date** `2015128` means `0805-02-13` (in oder to avoid any confusion: `13th of February 805 A.D.`)